# What is the proper way to dispose of used hydrochloric acid?

Tags: chemicals

What is the proper way to dispose of used [hydrochloric acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrochloric_acid) (e.g. [Sureklean 600](http://www.prosoco.com/Products/3dd244a3-cbd3-44da-8368-c1c4ec52f4aa))?  My municipal waste station does take toxic waste periodically but I was wondering if it can be safely flushed down the toilet.  It is very corrosive to metal and I know there is cast iron sewer pipe below the basement leaving the house to the street.  Also, is it safe to flush it from the environmental standpoint?

Comment: See http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/13780/what-should-i-do-with-leftover-sulfuric-acid-from-a-sump-pump-battery-backup

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HCl can be combined with baking soda to form salt water and CO2.

NaHCO3 + HCl = NaCl + H2O + CO2

NOTE this is exothermic and effervescent, mix slowly, adding the soda to the acid. In a wide-mouth container.

Comment: According to the MSDS, use Soda Ash or Lime to neutralize, 2.5 Lbs. of lime per gallon. The usual requirement is neutralize to 6-8 pH (neutral) and then dilute. Per their words "Neutralized materials may be discharged to a sanitary sewer with approval of the receiving treatment plant."

Comment: Watch for heat production.  Mix Chemicals slowly.

Comment: NEVER add baking soda to acid. Always add acid to baking soda (slowly and carefully). A baking soda splash is harmless. An acid splash can cause a lot of damage. Basic high school chemistry safety.

Comment: @PhilipNgai I might typically agree with you, but in an effervescent reaction like this I think you'll get better results by carefully adding the soda.

Comment: Because you prefer acid splashing and bubbling?

Comment: @PhilipNgai because effervescence at the top of a solution is less foamy and problematic than effervescence at the bottom of a solution. I know the typical mantra of "acid in"

Comment: Maybe it would be better to not pick a base that maximizes the production of bubbles.

Comment: I looked at several institutions' procedures and if you dilute the acid to 5% it seems safe to pour the base into the acid. Usually they dissolve the base in water also. I still think it's better to pick a base which is often used to generate large quantities of gas.

Comment: With bicarb, the stuff's going to bubble and foam horribly no matter how you mix things. If you have it, it's better to use slaked lime (calcium hydroxide, pickling lime, nixtamilization lime) to neutralize. No carbon dioxide-> no foaming.